# Python serialization of video frames adding disc memory

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, joblib

I am processing video frames in one of my projects and need to store them as individual images after some image processing operations on an AWS ECS Cluster. After image processing operations finish, I am serializing the frames using Python 3 pickle and uploading it to S3. However, each time serialization runs for a video clip, several hundreds of MBs of disc space is consumed. The video files are 25 fps and 20 to 30 sec long.

I have double checked and confirmed that I am removing all temporary files that I am creating and the image processing operations are not consuming this disk space.

I have also tried joblib to dump the frames and have seen the same behavior. Has anyone has this issue and if so how can it be resolved or avoided? Is there any other efficient means of serializing such video frames?

Comment: Is it possible that you are running out of memory and memory is getting paged to disk? Don't use pickle if you can help it, why are you using it and not just uploading the image?

Comment: I am actually processing an entire video file with 800 to 900 frames and then uploading the output frames for each frame. That is why I am pickling.